# Regex: Replace Arbitrary Number of Whitespace with Same Number of Another Character

Tags: regex, eclipse, text-editors, text-formatting

What I am trying to do is take a list that is formatted much like a table of contents & replace whitespace (single space characters, not tabs) between the left & right texts with dots, preserving only the two outermost whitespace characters.

So specifically, I want to take a list like this:

```
foo        url1
foobar     url2
foo bar    url3
```

And convert it to this:

```
foo ...... url1
foobar ... url2
foo bar .. url3
```

I am using the [Eclipse IDE](https://eclipse.org) for editing my text. I'm not familiar with the different regex engines, but I am guessing that it uses either Jakarta Regexp or java.util.regex (which I looked up on Wikipedia).

I can capture the whitespace characters in the *Find* field using "`( +)`", but I don't know how to convert them to the same number of dots in the *Replace with* field.

I did some Googling & came across [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/893929/replace-any-number-of-spaces-using-regular-expressions) (which is where I learned the "`( +)`" syntax). It sounds like it may be the same, or a similar question to mine. But I either didn't find my answer or I just didn't understand the answers given.

Comment: Any white space or just spaces? Your expression seems to be only about spaces. Then why not just replacing space with whatever character you like?

Comment: Because they don’t want to change spaces in the title; e.g., “foo bar” → “foo.bar”. Also, they don’t want to change “foo        url” to “foo........url”; they want “foo␣......␣url” (keeping the first and last space).

Comment: @Scott Correct.

Comment: This sounds like a question that has come up before, and so quite possibly it has already been answered here or on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com).  But I don’t remember the answer right now.  I’ll try to get back to this later when I have more time, but, until then, I suggest you search our site a bit harder.  Hint: [SE] has its own search engine, but sometimes you get better results using Google and saying ```site:superuser.com``` or ```site:unix.stackexchange.com```.

Comment: I did a brief search (about 15 minutes) and I didn’t find any exact matches, although [Using sed to replace all occurrences at the beginning with a matching number of replacement strings](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/433513/23408) and [Replace characters in matched line](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/352502/23408) are close. Since nobody has flagged your question as a duplicate, and you’ve gotten only one answer so far, I invented three answers myself (the first one is very similar to one of the ones in the questions I linked to). I hope you have access to `sed`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question explicitly states that titles will contain spaces. 
For sake of safety, I’m assuming that titles may contain dots (periods);
e.g., “The History of 3.14159” or “Dr. Doolittle’s Discovery”. 
My answers assume that there is *some* character
that will never appear in the table of contents;
specifically, they assume it is `@`. 
If you have `@` in your table,
replace it with some character that never appears
(e.g., `#`, `^`, `_`, `|`, etc.). 
If you really use every ASCII character,
you may need to use a character sequence, like `<@>`.

#### Three ways to do it with `sed`:

**Loop:**

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\( \)/\1@\2/; :loop; s/  @/ @./; t loop; s/@//'
```

- `s/\(.*\)\( \)/\1@\2/` finds the last space on the line
  and inserts a `@` before it.
- `:loop` is a label, like a mile marker.
- `s/  @/ @./` (that’s `s/␣␣@/␣@./`, for non-ambiguity) says,
  if there are two spaces before the `@`,
  replace them with `␣.` (space and dot), and move the `@` between them.
- `t loop` says, if the above substitution succeeded,
  jump back to the `:loop` marker and repeat. 
  Otherwise, continue to
- `s/@//`, which removes the `@`.

So the `foo bar` line in your table will be processed as follows:

```
Initial value:          foo bar    url3
s/\(.*\)\( \)/\1@\2/    foo bar   @ url3
s/  @/ @./              foo bar  @. url3
s/  @/ @./              foo bar @.. url3
s/  @/ @./              foo bar @.. url3        (Substitution fails, so don’t loop)
s/@//                   foo bar .. url3
Final output:           foo bar .. url3
```

**Overwhelming numbers:**

```
sed 's/\(.*\)\( \)/\1@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\2/; s/ [ @]\{20\}/ /; s/@/./g'
```

- `s/\(.*\)\( \)/\1@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@\2/`
  is very similar to the first `s` subcommand in the first solution;
  it finds the last space on the line
  and inserts a string of 20 `@` characters before it. 
  This should actually be a number that’s at least as large
  as the maximum number of dots you’ll ever need to insert on one line; e.g., 80. 
  Managing a string of 80 `@` characters would be awkward;
  you might want to replace this with

  - `s/\(.*\)\( \)/\1<@><@><@><@><@>\2/; s/<@>/@@@@@@@@/g`
    which inserts a string of five `<@>` sequences,
    and then replaces each one of them with a string of 16 `@` characters,
    resulting in 5×16=80 `@` characters.
- `s/ [ @]\{20\}/ /` finds a string of 20 consecutive characters
  that are either a space or an `@`, preceded by a space,
  and replaces it with just the preceding space. 
  Replace `20` with the number from the previous step.
- `s/@/./g` replaces each remaining `@` with a dot.

So the `foo` line in your table will be processed as follows:

```
Initial value:                  foo        url1
s/\(.*\)\( \)/\1@@@@...@@@@\2/  foo       @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@ url1
s/ [ @]\{20\}/ /                   _[↑↑↑↑↑↑remove↑↑↑↑↑↑]
                                foo @@@@@@ url1
s/@/./g                         foo ...... url1
```

**Use the “hold space”:**

```
sed 's/.*[^ ] /&@/; h; s/ /./g; s/\(\.*\)\./\1 /; x; G; s/@.*@//'
```

- `s/.*[^ ] /&@/` is *similar* to the previous commands;
  it finds the end of the title — to be precise,
  the last place where a non-blank character is followed by a space —
  and inserts an `@` after it.
- `h` copies the line to the hold space.
- `s/ /./g` replaces all spaces in the line with dots.
- `s/\(\.*\)\./\1 /` replaces the last dot with a space. 
  (This will need to change if the URL can contain dots,
  which, I guess, is likely.)
- `x` exchanges the pattern space and the hold space.
- `G` appends the hold space to the pattern space. 
  We now have, essentially, two copies of the line.
- `s/@.*@//` keeps the first part of the first copy
  and the second part of the second copy,
  getting rid of the stuff in the middle.

```
Initial value: foo bar    url3

                      Pattern space                            Hold space
s/.*[^ ] /&@/       foo bar @   url3
h                   foo bar @   url3                        foo bar @   url3
s/ /./g             foo.bar.@...url3                        foo bar @   url3
s/\(\.*\)\./\1 /    foo.bar.@.. url3                        foo bar @   url3
x                   foo bar @   url3                        foo.bar.@.. url3
G                   foo bar @   url3 foo.bar.@.. url3       foo.bar.@.. url3
s/@.*@//            foo bar .. url3                         foo.bar.@.. url3

Final output:   foo bar .. url3
```

Comment: Thank you for the very detailed explanation. Very helpful. The first two solutions work perfectly for me. The third one (hold space) is omitting the final space. So the final output is `foo bar ...url3`. Could it be related to the version of sed I am using? `$ sed --version` --> `sed (GNU sed) 4.8`

Answer (score 2):

You can do that with Notepad++

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `(?<!\S) (?= )`
- Replace with: `.`
- *check Wrap around*
- *check Regular expression*
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
(?<!    : Start negative lookbehind, make sure we have not
  \S    : a non-space character
)       : end lookbehind
        : a space
(?=     : start lookahead, make sure we have
        : a space
)       : en lookahead
```

**Replacement:**

```
.       : a dot
```

**Result for given example:**

```
foo ...... url1
foobar ... url2
foo bar .. url3
```

Comment: Looks interesting.  I don’t have Notepad++, so I can’t test this.  Can you explain why this doesn’t replace the first space after the title, resulting in ``foo.......␣url1``?

Comment: @Scott: I'm pretty sure it also works with SublimeText. A space is replaced only when there is not a non-space before it and a space after.

Comment: Oh … when there is a space after, and ***not** a **non-*** space before. I missed the double negative. Couldn’t you just do regular lookbehind for a space instead of a negative lookbehind for a non-space?

Comment: @Scott: No, if I use positive lookbehind (ie. `(?<=\s)`) the space before is mandatory, *a contrario* `(?<!\S)` make the space optionnal and that is the case after the first space has been replaced by a dot.

Comment: Well, I still don’t understand.    :-(   ⁠

Comment: @Scott: It's not easy to explain, but, just have a try with both expression then it will become clear.

Comment: This is adding a space between each dot for me: `foo . . .  url1`

Comment: @AntumDeluge: True with new version of Notepad++, it worked before as you can see [here](https://regex101.com/r/fQJuSY/1)